# lwc combobox component shows Select an option when the same value is selected the second time

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am not sure what is going on over here.
If I select the same value from the dropdown twice the second time it would say **Select an option** When I console log the selection change method I get the right values.

Here is how my combobox is setup in html

```
<lightning-combobox class="slds-var-m-top_xx-small" variant="label-hidden" value={selectedMobileNumber} options={mobileNumbers} onchange={handleMobileNumberChange} disabled={disableDropdown}>  </lightning-combobox>
```

And the below in JS

```
export default class OtpPhoneNumberSelection extends LightningElement {
//Values coming in from flow to LWC Component
@api mobileNumbersOfContact;
@api mobileNumberToSendOtp;
@api skipOneTimeCodeAuthentication = false;

//Contact Specific Properties
@track mobileNumbers;

//UI Specific Properties
@track selectedMobileNumber = 0;
@track disableDropdown = false;

connectedCallback() {

    let mobileNumberOrder = 0;
    let mobileNumbers = [];

    for (var number in this.mobileNumbersOfContact) {

        let maskedMobileNumber = this.mobileNumbersOfContact[number].slice(-4);
        
        mobileNumbers.push({
            label: '******'+maskedMobileNumber,
            value: mobileNumberOrder           
        });
        mobileNumberOrder++;
    }
    this.mobileNumbers = mobileNumbers;
    this.disableDropdown = this.mobileNumbers.length == 1 ? true : false;
    this.mobileNumberToSendOtp = this.mobileNumbersOfContact[this.selectedMobileNumber];
}

handleMobileNumberChange(event) {
    this.selectedMobileNumber = +event.detail.value;
    this.mobileNumberToSendOtp = this.mobileNumbersOfContact[this.selectedMobileNumber];
}
```

The values returned by this.mobileNumbers [image]

Comment: Why are you trying to convert the mobile number to a number?  Doesn't the combobox work with strings? I image the problem is the value of `selectedMobileNumber` is a number, but the values in `mobileNumbers` are strings

Comment: @NickCook the selectedMobileNumber is a number as it is what is used to select the right string from the list of strings. mobileNumbersOfContact has a list of phone numbers as string like this ["4036862873","4036587896"]. When a value is selected from the dropdown the event gets a value which is what is used to select the right number from the mobileNumbersOfContact array.

Comment: But why are you using the unary plus operator on your assignment to `this.selectedMobileNumber`?

Comment: @NickCook if I dont use unary then I wont be able to see the selected value on the dropdown component.

Comment: That makes no sense.  You're altering the value provided by your combobox. If you use the value directly provided by your combobox, you won't have any problems.  Have you tried removing the unary plus operator?

Comment: Yes I have tried it already as I have mentioned on one of my comments. Can you please provide sample code of how you would be doing this make it work as expected? If you could amend the code I posted above that would be great.

Comment: All you've said is "I wont be able to see the selected value on the dropdown", which makes no sense.  I think that's where your problem is, and you've created a new problem by altering your selected value.  Why don't you work out why the issue with "I wont be able to see the selected value on the dropdown"?

Comment: @NickCook as far I know the values from an array can only be selected by providing an index value, which is exactly what I am doing here. The event.detail.value comes as a string and I am converting it to a number to use it to select the right string from the list of strings.

Comment: And I remind you again I have tried it without using the unary operator multiple times so far.

Comment: Can you Edit your question to include the `mobileNumbers` variable?

Comment: @NickCook I have put in the whole code now.

Comment: "as far I know the values from an array can only be selected by providing an index value" - but you're not working with an array the way you're referring to it.  The combobox handles this for you.  `event.detail.value` will give you the value you specify in `{
            label: '******'+maskedMobileNumber,
            value: mobileNumberOrder           
        }`  The fact your comobox is displaying 'Select Option' means the value in `selectedMobileNumber` does not match any of the values in `mobileNumbers`

Comment: @NickCook the values that are returned from console.log(this.mobileNumbers) has been added to the original post. The actual issue is the combobox not showing any value if the same value is selected again from the dropdown. Let me make it clear - lets say the combobox has a value selected called 'Canada'. Now if I click on the dropdown and select Canada again then it would say Select an option.

Comment: And what is the value of `selectedMobileNumber` each time?  is it a string or a number?

Comment: It will be a number. It is all on the code the value of that variable.

Comment: And what is the value of selectedMobileNumber each time?

Comment: It depends on the selection made by the user. For e.g if the user selected the first item from the dropdown it will be 0 and if it is the second one it will be 1.

Comment: Tons of chat happened here, but was not able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a problem with the data types. The value inside of the lightning-combobox is a string. You can see that being passed in the event by checking the type.

```
console.log(typeof event.detail.value === 'string'); // true
console.log(typeof event.detail.value === 'number'); // false
```

You can also see that the value is a string like this.

```
console.log(typeof this.template.querySelector('lightning-combobox').value === 'string'); // true
```

You are force converting it to a number with the + unary operator. The component must be doing its own conversion through the value parameter. When you select the same one it is triggering a change event because of the type mismatch, but your internal `this.selectedMobileNumber` variable is not changed because it is set to the same integer, so it is not reacting to the change on the variable. This is why it works on a different option but not the same option.

In short, change the value property on your options to strings and it will work better.